# Formal way of saying "shy away"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I'm writing an essay where I say "you shouldn't shy away(?) from being yourself."

Formally, it would be "Thou shall not [formal word for "shy away"] from being thyself."

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Why thoust thinks that's formal? :P (No offence) Formal writing is different from archaic writing!

Comment: I'm not sure "formal" is the right word here, since "to be oneself" is an inherently "woolly" injunction in the first place (often used somewhat patronisingly). Formally you might be better just advising someone to ***act naturally***.

Comment: Not supposed to be archaic writing, but literary... it fits into the piece I am writing, which is in fact formal, but it does use some archaic words here and there.

Comment: @Aslan: I'd advise you to avoid archaic forms unless you're going to spend a lot more time familiarising yourself with them. MARamezani's "thoust" is a ridiculous parody that most native speakers would probably pick up on, but your own *thou shall not* is also incorrect (it's *thou **shalt** not*).

Comment: "Fear not to be but thyself."

Comment: @Aslan Maslin: In practice probably what people most often say is *"**Don't be afraid to be yourself**"* (where *"**Don't be afraid of being yourself**"* is credible, but I think less common). If you want a "mock archaic" version, maybe *"Be steadfast, and deny not thine own self"*. But for reasons I gave elsewhere, that would be better phrased as *"Be steadfast, and **true to thyself**"*.

Answer (score 2):

To me there are a few words which seem appropriate, where you could use a thesaurus to get just the correct meaning. Try the following on for size:

> you should not refrain from being yourself
>
> you should not forgo being yourself
>
> you should not abstain from being yourself

To me, not a native English speaker, all these seems to be better alternatives than your original suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Formal writing is not archaic writing, "thou" and "thy" are not formal. You *will* want to remove that contraction though. As to the main question:

> You should not **balk** at being yourself.

[Balk](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/balk) (verb) - to stop, as at an obstacle, and refuse to proceed or to do something specified (usually followed by at).

> You should not **hesitate** from being yourself.
>
> You should not **hesitate** to be yourself.

[Hesitate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hesitate) (verb) - to be reluctant or wait to act because of fear, indecision, or disinclination.

Either option is pretty good, "balk" is a much less common word though.

The resource you want for this kind of question is a [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/) - which lists synonyms and antonyms - essentially a backward dictionary, allowing you to find words that mean the thing you want to say.

Comment: It's a good word in other contexts, but I don't really think ***balk*** works very well here. You usually *balk at [some **specific** action being pressed on you, but which you're not prepared to take]*, but *being oneself* is more of a "continuous state of being". And *Don't hesitate **from** being yourself* just sounds plain ungrammatical to me, plus I don't think that verb works very well with *being yourself* either.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hence the second version with hesitate, which sounds more natural to me. I agree that "balk" isn't perfect, but neither is "shy away". If we want to say "don't not be yourself", but without the double negative or saying "be yourself" directly, I don't think there is a perfect word to use. Otherwise I would just rethink the sentence.

Comment: One can use a Thesaurus - essentially a backward dictionary - or one can use a [reverse dictionary](http://onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=shy+away+from), which really *is* a backward dictionary.

Comment: That's cool, I wasn't aware of that service. Without computers a Thesaurus is the best one could do.

Comment: @zeel: I think you're right. Since *being yourself* essentially means "doing what comes naturally", there's something slightly odd about urging someone ***not** to **avoid** it*. Personally I'd go for the simpler and more direct *[just] be yourself*. Circumlocution for the sake of it seems pointless at the best of times - even more so when the very thing you're urging is to be "open, direct, uncouched".